# R tikzDevice multiline title with maths expression

Tags: r, tikz

It is possible to input multiline math expression in the title of a graphic using tikzDevice?

I tried to add the amsmath package and used the following code but it didn't work out.

```
options(tikzLatexPackages=  c("\\usepackage{tikz}\n",
"\\usepackage[active,tightpage,psfixbb]{preview}
\n","\\PreviewEnvironment{pgfpicture}\n" , 
"\\setlength\\PreviewBorder{0pt}\n","\\usepackage{amsmath}\n"))


tikz(console = TRUE)
   plot(rnorm(500,sd=10)~rnorm(500,sd=5),
xlab="\\begin{align*} m=x \\\\ z=y \\end{align*}")
  dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually one does have to go that far to write multiline maths expressions. For example the following code does the job. I admittedly had to tweak the cex but it's not too difficult.

```
library(tikzDevice)
tikz("latexEx.tex",width=3.5,height=3.5,console=T)
plot(1, main="$y=x^{2}+ x^{5} +$")
mtext(paste("$\\frac{3}{4} x$"),
line=0.5,adj = 0.45,cex=1.2)
dev.off()
```

Width ggplot2

```
library(tikzDevice)
library(ggplot2)
tikz("latexEx.tex",width=3.5,height=3.5,console=T)
ggplot() + geom_blank() + labs(list(title="$y=x^{2}+ x^{5} +$ 
\n $\\frac{3}{4} x$")) + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.4))
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the aligned alternative,

```
xlab="$\\begin{aligned} m=x \\\\ z=y \\end{aligned}$"
```

[image]